# python pyqt with ui file to standalone app and exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

What is the best way to convert my python pyqt script, which uses a separate UI file for the PyQt UI, into a standalone Mac APP and an exe? I am on python 3.5 and using PyQt5, I have tried all the tutorials out there and I always seem to get an error with the ui file not being found or PyQt5 not being found, etc.

I have tried:
pyinstaller
py2exe
py2app

This is the error I get when trying to install pyinstaller (latest version from git):

```
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/5z/46_h30kx1d3cvwbbc2qlhs3h0000gn/T/pip-z4yhuehg-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/5z/46_h30kx1d3cvwbbc2qlhs3h0000gn/T/pip-rh7simww-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/5z/46_h30kx1d3cvwbbc2qlhs3h0000gn/T/pip-z4yhuehg-build/
```

Comment: pyinstaller definitely works with pyt5, what version are you using? Did you try the latest version from git?

Answer (score 0):

Try using pyinstaller. When using the latest version from GIT you should be able to handle pyqt5 (I have been successful with that in the past with [www.github.com/dickreuter/poker](http://www.github.com/dickreuter/poker), where I use pyqt5. With the -F option you can create a single executable file that runs in the OS where you generated it.

Comment: I edited my question.. thats the error I get when trying to install pyinstaller (latest version from git)

Comment: any idea why? I install it over and over says requirement satisifed, already installed etc but when i type the commands it says bash command not found.

Comment: You need to add it to the path environment variable

Comment: Also on my PC, I am able to successfully use pyinstaller however when I open the exe a terminal window pops up and then quits.

Comment: how do I add it to the path? sorry i never dealt with this with any other modules

Comment: You need to edit your windows environment variables. To launch the .exe start cmd from your start menu and then launch it manually. Then you will probably see an error message, that's why it closes. If you have gui and don't want a console you can use the --noconsole option in Pyinstaller.